# How to run a command within a bash script which gets it's arguments from a csv file

Tags: linux, bash, csv

From the command line I can run a python script with some arguments and all is well.

The problem I have is I'm trying to run this script (an a couple of others) many times using a bash scrip which reads the arguments each time from a CSV file.  The arguments include "account" which is a domain name, "password1" & "password2" which are passwords that may include special characters.

This is my script to far:

```
#!/bin/bash

INPUT=accountlist.csv
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=,
[ ! -f $INPUT ] && { echo "$INPUT file not found"; exit 99; }
while read -r account $password1 $password2
do

/tmp/migration_imapcopy $account $password1 $password2  
/tmp/migration_markmigrated $account
/tmp/migration_dnscheck abel $account
/tmp/migration_imapcopy $account $password1 $password2

done < $INPUT
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

My problem is when I run this script, the output from the various python scripts (those using the password variables) suggests that their is a problem logging in, i.e. the password variables are not correct.

It's almost as if the arguments aren't being supplied correctly each time.

Can anyone shed some light?

Comment: Quote variables: `"$account"`

Comment: you are using `abelpass` and `entapass` in `read`, yet `$password1` and `$password2` in the body of the while loop. Are those typo, or are they actually in your script?

Answer (score 2):

```
while read -r account abelpass entapass
```

You are reading `abelpass` & `entapass` but passing `password1` and `password2` ! Didn't you meant to use

```
while read -r account password1 password2
```

?

Comment: You can also prefix the `read` command with the correct value of `IFS`, avoiding the need to save the old value. `while IFS=, read -r account password1 password2`.

Comment: Sorry yes, I changed the names for posting on here but forgot those two.  This isn't the problem...  I've updated the post accordingly.  Thanks

Comment: @DaveLough Quote your variables "$account" "$password1: "$password2" for all calls. Did you check that arguments are received correctly in python script by printing them?

Comment: @KingsIndian how do i do that?

Comment: `print 'Number of arguments:', len(sys.argv)`
`print 'Arguments:', str(sys.argv)` 

Add these lines in your python scripts to see if the arguments are passed as you expected. You need to `import sys` if you haven't done already.